# Update table based on comparing data from different tables and priority

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have the below table which holds customer data:

```
DECLARE @customer TABLE (ref varchar(10), RepName varchar(10), City varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @customer
SELECT 'CustomerA', 'Tom',  'London' UNION ALL
SELECT 'CustomerC', 'John', 'London'
```

and I have 2 other identical tables SourceA and SourceB which holds customer data as well,

I have a script which compares data among these 3 tables and inserts the details into the below table:

```
DECLARE @diffs TABLE (ref varchar(10), existing_value varchar(100), nev_value varchar(100), source_table varchar(100), column_name varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @diffs
SELECT 'CustomerA', 'Tom', 'Tom A', 'SourceA', 'RepName' UNION ALL
SELECT 'CustomerA', 'Tom', 'Tom Ax', 'SourceB', 'RepName' UNION ALL
SELECT 'CustomerC', 'London', 'New York', 'SourceA', 'City'
```

This table highlights that the rep name in our Customer table is different than sourceA and sourceB. Current value is Tom, but sourceA has the value as Tom A and sourceB has it as Tom Ax, and it also highlights the difference in city but the city is only different in sourceA.

And I use the below table to understand which source to use when I am updating the Customers table:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (column_name varchar(100), source_to_use varchar(100), source_priority int)
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 'RepName', 'SourceA', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'RepName', 'SourceB', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'City', 'SourceB', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'City', 'SourceA', 2
```

Based on this I need to update the rep name with Tom A and city with New York based on the source_priority. Before writing the update statement I have tried to get the right rows using this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM @diffs d
LEFT OUTER JOIN @temp t ON t.column_name = d.column_name and d.source_table = t.source_to_use 
AND source_priority = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                        (
                            SELECT source_priority 
                            FROM @temp x
                            Where source_priority = 1 AND d.source_table = x.source_to_use 
                        ) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

But this does not give me what I want, is there anyway of querying these tables and update the customers table with the differences based on priority?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way that I can think to do this.  Flatten the three tables into a single table with different columns.  Then use `cross apply` to choose the value from `@temp`.  Here is an example that assumes that `customers` has rows for all customers:

```
select c.ref, repname.repname
from (select c.*, ca.repname as repname_a, ca.city = city_a,
             cb.repname as repname_b, cb.city as city_b
      from customers c left join
           customersa ca
           on c.ref = ca.ref left join
           customersb cb
           on c.ref = cb.ref
    ) c cross apply
    (select top 1
            (case when source_to_use = 'source_a' and repname_a is not null then name_a
                  when source_to_use = 'source_b' and repname_b is not null then repname_b
                  when source_to_use = 'source' and repname is not null then repname
             end) as repname
     from @temp t
     where t.column_name = 'repname'
     order by priority
    ) repname;
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have a @diff which contains the differences, can I not use that one?

Comment: Perhaps.  Based on the question, I do not fully understand what is in `@diffs`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a CTE. Something like this should work:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT d.*, t.source_priority
  FROM @diffs d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @temp t
    ON t.column_name = d.column_name
    AND d.source_table = t.source_to_use
), mins AS (
  SELECT ref, column_name, MIN(source_priority) source_priority
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY ref, column_name
)
SELECT cte.ref, cte.column_name, cte.new_value
FROM cte INNER JOIN mins
  ON cte.ref = mins.ref
  AND cte.column_name = mins.column_name
  AND cte.source_priority = mins.source_priority
```